# WebLogic: CDI deployment failure: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension?

Tags: java, hibernate, cdi, weblogic12c

I am migrating a project from Jboss 6.1 to weblogic 12.2.1 .
i am using jsf 2,ejb3 and hibernate

**Project structre :**

I have 2 WAR projects and 1 JAR project all includes in on EAR.

While deploying the EAR i got below exception  :

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension
```

However hibernate3.jar and hibernate-validator-cdi-5.0.0.final-sources is already in the EAR  build path.

The full stacktrace :

```
<Jul 14, 2016, 12:52:35,196 PM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1800397380822" for task "0" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension"
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:754)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jul 14, 2016, 12:52:35,216 PM EEST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 9 task for the application "Contest_EAR" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].> 
<Jul 14, 2016, 12:52:35,233 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "Contest_EAR".> 
<Jul 14, 2016, 12:52:35,233 PM EEST> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Error instantiating class org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:95)
    at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:754)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory: Provider com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory not found
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

My weblogic.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.8/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

    <wls:container-descriptor>

        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
//these lines resolved my jsf exception ..
            <wls:package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.stax2.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>

            <wls:package-name>org.bouncycastle.*</wls:package-name>

        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Can anyone help me with this exception?!

Comment: This must be a conflict between both cdi validator and hibernate validator, try using a 4.x hibernate validator.